# Dynamically set background image

Tags: php, html, css

I need to apply a background-image to a div that gets set dynamically. So the editor uploads an image on a specific page to a specific attribute and I catch this image then and display those.

Therefore I'd do something like this:

```
<div class="foo" style="background:url(<?php echo $attribute; ?>) no-repeat top right; background-size: 140px;">
```

Is there a better approach to it by **not** using style="..." ?

Thanks

Comment: Is Javascript an option?

Comment: For this particular project and task js is not really suitable; but maybe as a general hint indeed?

Comment: If you can use js you can add a statement to set the background image. With jQuery for example: `var imageUrl = <?php echo $url; ?>; $('myObject').css('background-image', imageUrl);` that should keep the code cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You approach is correct but I would change something.

In the `css` I would make this:

```
.foo {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    background-size: 140px;
}
```

And in the `HTML` i would only keep the url.

```
<div class="foo" style="background:url(<?php echo $attribute; ?>);">
```

This way on the server-side it's easier to see where you have dynamic content. And you only need to change the url for the corresponding image.

So if later you work with another developer he knows exactly where he should change the images without going to your css.

Comment: Yeah. I though the exact same as I wrote those lines with the mediaqueries.

Answer (score 3):

If you fundamentally don't want to use style html attribute, you could create many css classes with description of *background-image* property

```
.my-background { 
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: top right;
     background-size: 140px
}
.my-background_custom2 {
     backgroud-image: url('/path/1/to/your/image.png') 
}
.my-background_custom2 {
     backgroud-image: url('/path/2/to/your/image.png') 
}
```

And html generation will look like:

```
<div class="foo my-background my-background-<?= $attribute ?>">
```

---

But if you choose this solution and number of css classes will be large
I recommend you **use style attribute** despite your desire to refuse of this attribute

Answer (score 3):

```
you can use this  html & php code:

HTML:
<style type="text/css">
.bannar {    
    width: 100%;
    height: 361px;
    background: no-repeat center;   
}
</style>

PHP:

<div class="bannar" 
style="background-image: url('<?php echo $this->webroot . 'companyImages/bannar' . '/' . $company_page[0]['companypages']['bannar']; ?>')">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have the css defined in the php side so it will look like that:

```
<?php
    $backgroundCss = '<style>#uniqueback{
            background:url('.$attribute.') no-repeat top right; background-size: 140px;
            };</style>';
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <?php echo $backgroundCss;?>

    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="uniqueback" class="foo" ></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually you can make it nicer I will improve the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could point to background.jpg, for all users, but redirect that request to a backend (PHP?) function instead (you redirect with .htaccess for apache). And in this function you could check the location of the image that would exist if the user had uploaded an image, and then return this binary string as a JPEG. Then you could actually link to background.jpg in the external CSS.